# I don't know how to create an extra orbiting circle in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I'am currently pretty new to JavaScript and I really need some help, to understand how certain stuff works. I found one javascript code in fiddle, where one rectangle is moving around on a circular track.

Now i'am trying to make something like solarsystem out of it. Where multiple circles are moving around sun with different speed. I manged to change rectangle to a circle, but I don't know how to create others (with different color, size and speed). If anyone happens to know the answer it would be great!

Ok heres code.

```
<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=500></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
var dd = 3;
var angle = 0;
var cx = 200;
var cy = 275;
var radius = 80;

ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
ctx.strokeStyle = "lightgray";

function draw(x, y) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x - 8/2,y - 5,12 ,0 ,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
};

var fps = 60;

window.requestAnimFrame = (function (callback) {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / fps);
    };
})();

function animate() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        requestAnimFrame(animate);

        // increase the angle of rotation
        angle += Math.acos(1-Math.pow(dd/radius,2)/2);

        // calculate the new ball.x / ball.y
        var newX = cx + radius * Math.cos(angle);
        var newY = cy + radius * Math.sin(angle);
        // draw
        draw(newX, newY);

        // draw the centerpoint 
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();

    }, 1000 / fps);
}
animate();
</script>
```

Comment: This question would be better if you gave a specific question, rather than saying "I don't know how".  Perhaps "How do I animate multiple things simultaneously on an HTML canvas?"

Comment: Thanks Pheonixblade, I try to repair my question. 
Does somebody know how to create other circles like the one which are moving there, with different color, size, orbit size and speed ? 
I tried to add them by myself, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Try taking a look at this: http://www.kirupa.com/html5/animating_many_things_on_a_canvas.htm

Comment: You are already changing variables over time, and you are already drawing a circle with those variables.  So you have all the pieces you need to do this. What's _not_ clear is what part you are stuck on. What _technical detail_ is stopping you from completing your task? Or is it that you don't even know how the code you pasted works? Because if that's it, you should really start there and learn what each part of this code does.

Comment: Thank you so much! I started studying from there.

Comment: @user3175229 if what I gave you answered your question, please make sure to mark it as such :)

Comment: Thanks Alex Wayne for reply.
You are right I don't really understand how it works. I manged to add other circles but not on the other orbit. I created two drawing functions and also another animate function, which were similar to a previous one. I also got another different colored planet moving around there. But one orbit stayed for some seconds and then other appeared and first disapered. I didn't managed to get them both on a screen at same time. I think that theres something to do with setTimeout

Comment: @Pheonixblade9, sure will mark it

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a complete example of animating multiple circles on an HTML canvas](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/animating_many_things_on_a_canvas.htm):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="stuff, to, help, search, engines, not" name="keywords">
<meta content="What this page is about." name="description">
<meta content="A Whole Lotta' Circles!" name="title">
<title>A Whole Lotta' Circles!</title>

<style>
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    #myCanvas {
        border: 1px #CCC solid;
    }
</style>


</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500">

        </canvas>
    </div>

    <script>

        var mainCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var mainContext = mainCanvas.getContext('2d');

        var circles = new Array();

        var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
                                    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                                    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                                    window.msRequestAnimationFrame;


        function Circle(radius, speed, width, xPos, yPos) {
            this.radius = radius;
            this.speed = speed;
            this.width = width;
            this.xPos = xPos;
            this.yPos = yPos;
            this.opacity = .05 + Math.random() * .5;

            this.counter = 0;

            var signHelper = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

            if (signHelper == 1) {
                this.sign = -1;
            } else {
                this.sign = 1;
            }
        }

        Circle.prototype.update = function () {

            this.counter += this.sign * this.speed;

            mainContext.beginPath();

            mainContext.arc(this.xPos + Math.cos(this.counter / 100) * this.radius, 
                            this.yPos + Math.sin(this.counter / 100) * this.radius, 
                            this.width, 
                            0, 
                            Math.PI * 2,
                            false);

            mainContext.closePath();

            mainContext.fillStyle = 'rgba(185, 211, 238,' + this.opacity + ')';
            mainContext.fill();
        };

        function drawCircles() {
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                var randomX = Math.round(-200 + Math.random() * 700);
                var randomY = Math.round(-200 + Math.random() * 700);
                var speed = .2 + Math.random() * 3;
                var size = 5 + Math.random() * 100;

                var circle = new Circle(100, speed, size, randomX, randomY);
                circles.push(circle);
            }
            draw();
        }
        drawCircles();

        function draw() {
            mainContext.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

            for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
                var myCircle = circles[i];
                myCircle.update();
            }
            requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```